# hide <tr> based on selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I want to hide a table row based on the value selected from a radio button.
Those radio buttons were created based on value selected from a dropdown list box.

Here is my code

**HTML code for listbox**

```
<select name="txtLT" id="LT" >
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#LT").change(function() {
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        $("#tblerow").html('');
        if(selVal == 'c') {
            $("#tblerow").append('<td><input type="radio" id="cmpof" name="cmpof" value="1" onclick="show()" />1 <input type="radio" id="cmpof"  name="cmpof" value="2"  onclick="hide()"/>2</td>');            
        }
    });
});
```

Now if radio button 2 is selected, then the table row with tr2 should disappear.
Please help me to find the solution.

**EDIT**

I tried the following JavaScript, but it does not hide the row.

```
function show() { document.getElementById('sbjrow').style.display = 'block'; }
function hide() { document.getElementById('sbjrow').style.display = 'none'; }
```

Could you please suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: The default value for the table row display property defined in the default HTML style sheet is `table-row`, not `block`. Of course not all browsers follow that, so it's preferable when showing elements to set their display property to `''` (empty string), that way the property returns to either the default value or whatever value the element inherits through CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `hide` and `show` function of jQuery like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('#LT').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'c') {
            $('.radios').show();
        } else {
            $('.radios').hide();
        }
    });
    $('input[name=cmpof]').change(function () {
        if ($('#LT').val() == 'c' && $(this).val() == 'bar') {
           $('#table tr').eq(1).hide(); 
        } else {
           $('#table tr').eq(1).show(); 
        }
    });
});
```

If you don't want the table row to show up by default, just do it with css.

JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/AX5TJ/1/
Updated version that may be closer to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/AX5TJ/2/

Also be carefull, you have a syntax error in your script : when you define `$("#LT").change(function() {`, you have to close with `});`

Comment: when c is selected it displays radio buttons 1 & 2 and onclick of that radio button 2 only tr should be hided and not on selecting c in list box.